# Angular 6, node, passport and OAuth2

Tags: angular, cors, passport.js

I want to allow a user of my angular-cli v6 app to login with github credentials. I am using passport, and passport-github.

the key parts in the node server is this

```
    passport.use(
        new Strategy(
            {
                clientID: '<clientID>',
                clientSecret: '<ClientSecret>',
                callbackURL: 'http://myapp/authenticated'
            },
            (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
                return cb(null, profile);
            }
        )
    );

    this.config.app.get(
        '/login',
        passport.authenticate('github', {
            scope: [
                'user',
                'notifications',
                'gist',
                'repo',
                'admin:org',
                'admin:public_key',
                'admin:repo_hook',
                'admin:org_hook'
            ]
        })
    );

    this.config.app.get(
        '/authenticated',
        passport.authenticate('github', {
            successRedirect: '/home',
            failureRedirect: '/signin',

            session: false
        }),
        (req, res) => {
            res.redirect('/home');
        }
    );
}
```

so I fire up ng-serve and get my login form (on /signin). When I press the get button, the code does this

```
public async login(username: string, password: string) {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    };

    const result = await this.http
        .get<any>('/login', httpOptions)
        .toPromise();
```

at this point, I get network and console errors

```
404 https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect....
```

and

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myapp' is therefore not allowed access.
```

however, if I change the angular code to read

```
public async login(username: string, password: string) {
    window.open('/login', '_self');
```

then the app is authorised against github, and the user redirected to the home page

what am I doing wrong with the angular http client that would generate the 404 and cors error, when the same url entered directly from  the browser address bar works just fine ?

**update #1** : I've noticed that the request to https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize for the `window.open('/login'` is a **GET** , but the angular http client is an **OPTIONS** which may explain the 404

**update #2** : If I remove the `httpOptions` from the request, the 404 goes away ... but not the CORS error in the console

public async login(username: string, password: string) {

```
const result = await this.http
    .get<any>('/login')
    .toPromise();
```

**update #3** : if I have `href="'/login'"` in the button html then login works just fine, no cors error. So I suppose I've now reached the point of how to simulate a `href` call in an angular method

Answer (score 0):

You can’t simulate an href call and you can’t do the login in a “behind the scenes” XHR request.  To do this kind of login you have to actually send the user to the site.

If you need to do that programmatically then do:

`window.location.href = ...`

Comment: thanks for the info. I'm just confused about why navigating in the browser to "http://foo/login" (or href="/login" works, but using the angular client http.get('/login') generates a CORS

Comment: CORS is designed to prevent this very thing.  There is a difference between a call which sends a user to a site and one that happens “behind the scenes” via an XHR request (which is what Angular uses in their http service).  The behind the scenes calls could be used maliciously by a site.  This is called an XSS attack.  Chrome enforces CORS to try and keep Github safe from this kind of attack.

Comment: Imagine this call was allowed.  You could take the HTML returned by Guthub and render it to the user.  The user would then enter their Github username / password on your site thinking they are on Github and you could steal that info.

Comment: Or you could just make a backend call to Github to delete all a user’s repositories and, if the user had logged into Github recently, their session cookies would be inserted by Chrome, Github would authorize the request and you just destroyed their account.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. Suppose I'm going to have to go and find some examples of node, angular and passport oauth to see how it's done ;)

Comment: Are you wanting the user to login to your page with Github or do you have some other authentication mechanism in place and you just want to allow your site to make calls to Github on the user's behalf?  If the former,  then you probably want to enable session authentication in Passport.  Typically you do the delegated authentication once and then cache the authentication result in an HTTP session for future requests.